# Alternative to pivot tables

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

This may seem a bit odd

But I'm trying to think of a way to make a pivot table using a single row across multiple columns.

Rather than having multiple items vertically and amounts in an adjacent column I was wanting to have several columns side by side in a single row in the order of item, amount, item, amount, etc. then total when the items are identical.

So in some columns there would be recurring items where I would like to sum the amount.

The concept is to create unique shopping lists for my nutrition clients.

I have new clients signing up so I was thinking an array formula with a sum function using unique function to aggregate ingredients.

But I can't think of a way to have this behave like a pivot table where it will automatically total items without it being in a single table.

Is what I'm suggesting possible?

Comment: Demo in a sheet what the data looks like and what your desired result would be.  here's a blank:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZ2_n-NeEfPBsDVBwzq_PXiA2kocDSKrtYJgBeMc-N8/edit

Comment: I've input the data into the spreadsheet and built it how I would like it to operate